# Why the use of cvLoadImage of OpenCV always return NULL on IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I write some code to run on the **iPad**, I use cvLoadImage() to read image from `Bundle Resources`, but it always return `NULL`, I don't know why?

Comment: The path to the file is probably wrong.

Comment: i add image to Bundle Resources,i think it does't need path,i just write the image's name. it's like "cvLoadImage("lena.jpg");"

Comment: You shouldn't make assumptions about the current working directory. Get the path to the bundle first and prefix your filename with the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load an image from your app bundle directly into OpenCV … Getting a proper cv::Mat involves two steps:

1.) Load your image using UIImage
2.) Convert the UIImage to a cv::Mat

Which looks like this:

```
cv::Mat img = [UIImageCVMatConverter cvMatFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]];
```

Grab the UIImageCVMatConverter class from this thread: [OpenCV install in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214273/opencv-install-in-xcode/12216556#12216556)

Hope that helps!

Comment: In fact,I use another way to load image,but your answer is right,too

Comment: Please, can you explain why the images in the bundle can't be loaded directly with opencv functions?

Answer (score 0):

use directly

```
[UIImage imageWithNamed:@"photo.png"];
```

if the image is in Bundle you can use directly.

Comment: but i need to processing this image with the method of OpenCV